# How to prevent images from overlapping in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
def getImage(path):
    return OffsetImage(plt.imread(path), zoom=0.25)

paths = dcmergedf['IMAGE_PATH']
y = dcmergedf['PAB_FLUX']/dcmergedf['HA_FLUX']
x = dcmergedf['HA_FLUX']/dcmergedf['HB_FLUX']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15), tight_layout=True)
ax.scatter(x, y) 
for x0, y0, path in zip(x, y, paths):
    ab = AnnotationBbox(getImage(path), (x0, y0), frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
ax.axis([0.1,10,0.01,2])
```

which yields the following plot

[image: plot]

Is there a clean way (not manually placing the images or changing the size) to get the images to spread/not overlap? They don't need to be exactly on the coordinates.

Comment: You could try multiplying the x and y values by some number to increase the distance between each point.

Comment: That's effectively the same as just increasing the size of the figure (so the images would be smaller relative to the size of the figure). What I need is a way to move the figures around in a smart way to get them as close to their original points as possible with no overlap.

Comment: Trying being more specific in your question then.

Comment: How would you do it as a human being?  Look at the cluster of three in the bottom center.  Who wins?  Who has to move?  If you can figure out how YOU would do it, then you can tell the computer how to do it.

Comment: @TimRoberts I suppose the question is how to go about doing that. Obviously I could move them manually to close by positions, but I am looking for a smarter way (something similar to ```constrained_layout``` or ```tight_layout```, which do not do the trick). Manually moving all of them like a human would become very tedious for much larger data sets.